# Develop for Windows CE 6 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, emulation, windows-ce

I'm trying to develop an application for a Windows CE 6 device. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 and am able to create a Smart Device application, but when I try run it to see if it works, I get:

Error   1   ActiveSync bootstrap initialization failed. Please connect/cradle a real device or download the User-level Windows Mobile Device Center Application from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=67763    Device Connectivity Component

Following the link just takes me to the Windows Mobile site and I can't connect the actual device as I don't have the right cable. I already have Windows Mobile Device Center on my PC anyway.

Please help, I really need to get this sorted as I am nearing a deadline!!

*Edit*

Otherwise, would a Pocket PC application work on a Windows CE device?

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of development using CE 6.0 target devices and a 64-bit development PC, so it's definitely supported.  How are you connecting to the device?  WMDC is not needed (and if the target has any sort of ethernet, I'd highly recommend avoiding WMDC at all costs). You should be running ConManClient2.exe and then CMAccept.exe over on the CE device and connecting that way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't have a cable for the device so I'm trying to run it through an emulator that's built into Visual Studio if that's possible?

Comment: Turns out my Nokia Lumia cable works with it so I now have it connected to my PC via USB. When I try run it I get the error "Connect to device failed".

Comment: If you insist on using USB, you might try running the ActiveCync device-side piece manually (cemgrc.exe).  Does WMDC say the device is connected?  If not, Studio isn't going to make that connection.